# Error when value not present

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I am using the code below several times over in one sub for different values not just "CPNEC". It works fine where there is a range with that value on the spreadsheet but falls over it the value does not exist. This is a routine I want to use every month where there will sometimes be none of a certain value in my data so I need it to be able to move onto the next value without falling over. Can anyone help me please.

```
Sub SelectCPNEC()
    ' Figure out where the "CPNEC" data starts.
    For nRow = 1 To 65536
    If Range("A" & nRow).Value = "CPNEC" Then
    nStart = nRow
    Exit For
    End If
    Next nRow

    ' Figure out where the "CPNEC" data ends.
    For nRow = nStart To 65536
    If Range("a" & nRow).Value <> "CPNEC" Then
    nEnd = nRow
    Exit For
    End If
    Next nRow
    nEnd = nEnd - 1

    'Select the range required

    Range("A" & nStart & ":G" & nEnd).Select

    'Now copy and paste into the right worksheet

    Selection.Copy
    Application.Goto ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("CPNEC").Cells(1, 1)
    ActiveSheet.Paste

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

When no matching value exists, `nStart` keeps the default value of `0`. This results in an error on this line.

```
If Range("a" & nRow).Value <> "CPNEC" Then
```

because `A0` is not a valid range reference. To get around this problem (and to save yourself some unnecessary looping), add a conditional check for `nStart = 0` after the first loop. If it is zero, exit the sub; otherwise, continue. This should avoid errors stopping your code when no match is found.

```
Sub SelectCPNEC()
    ' Figure out where the "CPNEC" data starts.
    For nRow = 1 To 65536
    If Range("A" & nRow).Value = "CPNEC" Then
    nStart = nRow
    Exit For
    End If
    Next nRow

    If nStart > 0 Then
        ' Figure out where the "CPNEC" data ends.
        For nRow = nStart To 65536
        If Range("A" & nRow).Value <> "CPNEC" Then
        nEnd = nRow
        Exit For
        End If
        Next nRow
        nEnd = nEnd - 1

        'Select the range required

        Range("A" & nStart & ":G" & nEnd).Select

        'Now copy and paste into the right worksheet

        Selection.Copy
        Application.Goto ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("CPNEC").Cells(1, 1)
        ActiveSheet.Paste
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Excellll explains it. But since you handle for loops well, you could also search for the string on each cell and if the macro finds it, copy the entire row to the right worksheet. You won't get an error if the value doesnt exist.

```
For Each cell In Range("A1: A65536")
    If cell.Value = "CPNEC" Then
        cell.EntireRow.Copy Workbooks.Open("otherWorkbook.xls").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)
    End If
Next cell
```

There should be some info in cell "A1" and in cell "A2", like the column titles. `.End(xlDown)` and `.Offset(1,0)` will find the first empty row to paste the info.